# Getting syntax error in Python code step in zap

Tags: python, zapier

I’m getting a syntax error and I can’t understand why.

I’m writing a simple Zap Code step to set up some values based on input values with a series of if-else statements.

```
if input_data.['workbench'] == 'True':
    workbench = 'False'
else:
    workbench = 'N.A.'
if input_data.['office'] == 'True':
    office = 'False'
else:
    office = 'N.A.’   # this is the line with the error
```

When I do a test run of this Python in a Zapier Code step, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax (`<string>`, line 8)

I don’t expect to get a syntax error at all, and I don’t understand why one should occur at line 8 when there is a similar if-else construct prior to that which includes line 8.

There are similar, subsequent constructs before a final return statement (which is a Zapier mechanism).

Comment: `input_data.['workbench']` is invalid Python. Did you mean `input_data['workbench']`? (Also... you never said which line is line 8.)

Comment: @furas - That is the exact error message I got within Zapier. Isn’t it in the question as text? I haven’t posted a screenshot?

Comment: @Amadan Yes - that was the problem I think. Line 8 position implied by comment indicating that was the error, and, it actually *is*... line 8.

Comment: You show only last line of error message and there can be other useful information - for example which line is 8?. You don't have it as screenshot  but because many new users make the same mistakes when they put error so I don't write text "allways put ..." manually but I have shortcut which puts it for me - and this text explain all common mistakes with error - like screenshots.

Comment: @furas I have amended the error section with a code guard so that the <string> is no longer occluded. That is the entire error message. I’d be a little more judicious in your use of that shortcut in future.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a simple typo: The last character on this line is not a tick (`'`), but an apostrophe (`’`):

```
office = 'N.A.’
```

Answer (score 1):

You see in the line that caused the error, the comment is highlighted as red (may be different colors in other IDEs), which indicates it is recognized as part of a string. Hence the error is cause by the string literal not closing appropriately, because of the typo of `'`.